# What is the best way (performance driven) to convert and write variables to a file in c++?

Tags: c++, fstream, sstream

I want to write something like this to a file:

```
0x050 addik r13, r0, 4496
0x054 addik r2, r0, 2224
0x058 addik r1, r0, 7536
0x05c brlid r15, 200
...
```

And so on... Its a program instruction trace which will have thousands of lines.

I am reading from an 'elf' decoding the instruction, creating an object, setting its address, instruction, name and registers parameters and then writing it in the above format to a file.

What it is the best way, measuring in speed/performance, to do this?

Now I have this (still just hexadecimals) and I don't know if it is the best way  to continue writing my code:

Converting function:

```
static std::string toHex(const T &i) {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "0x" 
           << std::setfill ('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T)*2) 
           << std::hex << i;
    return stream.str();
};
```

And the writing:

```
while((newInstruction = manager->newInstruction())){
    stream  << Utils::toHex(newInstruction->getAddress())
            << " "
            << Utils::toHex(newInstruction->getInstruction())
            << endl;
    trace->writeFile(stream.str());
    stream.str(std::string());
}
```

EDIT:

So I have reached a faster solution based on the answers.

For one I implemented the solution given by [Escualo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104427/escualo) to stop creating objects each time I read a new instruction.

And then I read the answer given by [Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews) and gave me the idea to not write to my file at every instruction read, so the stringstream now works like a buffer with size 1024, and when it surpasses that value then writes the stream to the file:

```
while((newInstruction = manager->newInstruction())){
    stream  << myHex<unsigned int> << newInstruction->getAddress() << ' '
            << myHex<uint32_t> << newInstruction->getInstruction();
    if(stream.tellp() > 1024){
        trace->writeFile(stream.str());
        stream.str(std::string());
    }
}
```

Comment: how is `writeFile()` coded?

Comment: What makes speed/performance the most important aspect of this code (rather than readability, maintainability, reusability, or other nice things)? I ask because when speed _really_ is important, the fastest way to write variables to a file is to directly copy the bytes (which are not human readable) and run a slower program later, when time is no longer the most important thing, to translate them to human-readable text.

Comment: The issue I have is that it will have to manage assembly instructions from another programs, which can reach easily one million instructions, and I have to decode every instruction which takes time, then detect sequences which takes even more time and then write everything to files.

Comment: Which part of your code has your profiling identified as the bottleneck, that just isn't fast enough?

Comment: `void File::writeFile(const string &s){
 if(file.is_open())
  file << s << endl;
 else
  return;
}`

Comment: My program in C is doing the same plus the decoding every instruction and detect patterns in the instruction trace and it is taking less time to do it. I am concerned that when it is fully coded in C++ will take a large amount of time to do everything.

Comment: I think the bottleneck is using stringstreams and then writing it to a file.

Comment: Profiling relieves you of the erroneous task of *guessing, where the bottleneck is*.

Comment: If the program already works in C, why are you recoding it?

Comment: For scalability. I need to add more functionality now and it will grow even bigger after I stop working on it, because other people will work whith it too, so I took the decision to recode it in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, I would avoid creating and destroying an `std::stringstream` for every call to your formatting function.

Recall that the I/O manipulators are nothing but functions which return the stream itself. For example, a manipulator doing exactly what you indicated above, but without resorting to a temporary `std::stringstream` could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T,
         typename CharT,
         typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT> >
inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
myhex(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os) {
  return os << "0x"
            << std::setfill('0')
            << std::setw(2 * sizeof(T))
            << std::hex;
}

int main() {
  int x;
  std::cout << myhex<int> << &x << std::endl;
}
```

to print (for example):

```
0x0x7fff5926cf9c
```

To clarify: I do not know why you choose the fill, width, prefix, and format; I am just showing you how to create an I/O manipulator that does not entail creating and destroying temporary objects.

Notice that the manipulator will work with any `std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>` such as `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::ofstream`, and `std::stringstream`.

Comment: I liked the idea of not creating a disposable object everytime I read an instruction, but I am struggling with the solution you presented since I am getting this compiling error:
`main.cpp:23: error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
`

Comment: So, just do what the compiler tells you: add `-std=c++0x` to your compilation line (this tells the compiler to use the C++11 standard).

Comment: I tried it and the running time certainly decreased.

Answer (score 1):

Since file I/O is slower than the time for formatting, I suggest formatting into a buffer, the block writing the buffer to the file.

```
char text_buffer[1024];
unsigned int bytes_formatted = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  int chars_formatted = snprintf(&text_buffer[bytes_formatted],
                                 1024-bytes_formatted,
                                 "hello %d", i);
  if (chars_formatted > 0)
  {
    bytes_formatted += chars_formatted;
  }
}
my_file.write(text_buffer, bytes_formatted);
```

Most file I/O operations have a constant overhead regardless of the operation.  So the more data that can be written during one operation, the better.